# Proof regarding a divergent sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

How to show that if $x_n$ diverges and $x_0$ is any number, then there exists $\epsilon$ and a subsequence ${x_n}_k$ such that $|{x_n}_k-x_0|>\epsilon$ for all k. Any hints or solutions welcome.

Comment: If $x_n$ diverges it means that don't converges to $x_0$ then negate the convergence (the limit definition) and you have your result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Sketch:*

Suppose $(x_n)$ diverges. Then by definition given any $x_0 \in \Bbb R $ there is an $\epsilon \gt 0$ such that for any $n \in \Bbb N$ there exists another natural number $m \ge n$ such that $ |x_m  - x_0 |\ge \epsilon$.

Now start iwth $1$. Let $r_1$ be the natural number ($m$) that satisfies this mentioned condition. Now go to $r_1 + 1$. Let $r_2$ be the natural number which satisfies this condition for $r_1 + 1$. Keep going and you will get a strictly increasing sequence of natural numbers $(r_n)$ such that $|x_{r_n} - x_0| \ge \epsilon$.